# Как посчитать числа в Jpannel

Tags: java

Я не опытный программист прошу помощи с таким вопросом как посчитать числа на Jpannel.Используя int пишет ошибку что оператор + не может быть принят к java.swing[image: что не так?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В текстовом поле сохраняется текст. Даже если там значение `200`, то это не число, а строка `"200"`. Если Вам надо получить строку преобразуйте числа в строку и соединяйте строки. Если надо выполнить арифметические операции, переведите текст в числа и сохраните в переменные числового типа. С ними уже оперируете. Прочитайте про [преобразование типов в Java](http://study-java.ru/uroki-java/urok-7-preobrazovanie-tipov-v-java/) Удачи.